# UItextfield next feature in super class

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

In my application I have many `viewcontrollers` which are using `textfields` subclass.
Till now they if I press return it will resign and user need to select the second one.

Now what i want to implement when user press `next` key from keyboard the next `textfield` will become first responder.

The challenge is (actually my client) I don't want to touch `viewcontrollers`.

I have tried to achieve this but not found a generic solution.

**I know there are good libraries available like `iqkeyboardmanager` but i can not use that:**

Here is my simple code which written in super class

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder] ;
    return NO ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No longer developing in Objective-C. But I think you need something like this:

```c
if ([textField isEqual:textField1]) {
    [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
} else if ([textField isEqual:textField2]) {
    [textField3 becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: i can't access the object like above

Answer (score 0):

By following https://github.com/simonbs/BSKeyboardControls create your own custom class which has the same code of that link. Pass all textfields array first and hide toolbar there. Next in your textFieldShouldReturn method pass textField to activeField of BSKeyboardControls